# php script that will check for cookie,if cookie yes go to url, if no cookie run script

Tags: php

Im trying to create a php script that will check for cookie. If cookie exist it goes to a page. If the cookie does not exist it it will run script. however its not quiet working I think its the index.php code below thats the issue.
gateway.php

```
 <?php
 $value = "mobilecookie";
 /*setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)*/
 setcookie("mobilecookie",$value, time()+60*60*24*30);
 ?>
```

index.php

```
 <?php
 if( $.cookie('mobilecookie') == null ) { 
 require_once("gateway/scripts/mobile.php");
 window.location.replace('http://domian.com/index.php');
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: i was working on it you were just too fast

Comment: `window.location.replace()` is not PHP, just like `$.cookie`.

Comment: You do realise that if somebody has cookies disabled this will result in a infinite loop? Perhaps you should add a check if you already tried to set the cookie

Answer (score 3):

use

```
header("Location: http://domian.com/index.php");
exit;
```

<sup>1</sup> to redirect the user

And cookie is read by `$_COOKIE['mobilecookie']`

---

<sup>1</sup>: Do **NOT** output anything (even UTF-8 BOM) before `header`

Answer (score 0):

If you require a delay, I would use your PHP to create a Javascript redirect so that way the page will load before you do the redirect.

If you would like an immediate redirect, you should use the PHP `header()` function.

Another note being that Cookies are sent out using a header, so you can not set a cooke and retrieve its value in the same instance of a script, the page must be reloaded to get the new value.